# ASP.NET: Changed DOM not accessible at debug

Tags: javascript, asp.net, debugging

I got some JS code changing the visibility of an object from display: none to display: block (jQuery show + hide). 
When I now try to extract the visibility in C# by

```
webControl.Style["display"]
```

I get "none" instead of "block". If I check it in browser waiting at the breakpoint the control is visible and firebug shows the correct "block"-value.

The .NET-breakpoint is triggered by pressing a button causing a postback.

What's going on here? Is it a timing problem? I do a jQuery show on each reload.

Comment: Post some more detail about your question so that people here may suggest some work-around or correct way of achieving your purpose..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe style attributes are posted back to the server...

Comment: You'll have to come up with a workaround... I would imagine a hidden field could be populated with the id of the object/element, and then you could check the hidden field on postback to determine which thing was shown.